# Swift 3: How to make sure that data is set before presenting in next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using prepare for segue to set a dictionary variable in another view controller. But the issue is the view controller opens the map without the data. How can I make sure I go to next view controller only after the dictionary variable data has been set.

Here is my code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showMapSegue"
        {
            if let mapVC = segue.destination as? MapVC
            {
                if vendorStoreKeys.count != 0{
                    mapVC.vendorStore = vendorStoreKeys
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

But the vendor store array in next view controller is still empty when the controller is visible. It sets the data after some time but at that point I am unable to reload that view controller so I need to make sure I don't go to next view controller before the **mapVC.vendorStore** variable is properly set.

Comment: what are you doing in your viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear method in your MapVC. Ideally it will never open screen before calling prepare so something else is delaying your use of vendorStore property

Comment: var vendorStore = Dictionary<String,Int>() 

Here is the dictionary .... I am just setting a map with this dictionary

Comment: @MoazKhan share destination view controller code . specially where your map loaded data code

Comment: @MoazKhan Please check your segue.identifier = "showMapSegue" is correct ? and check your vendorStoreKeys.count > o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Prepare for should have set the data before calling and it was. Issue was I actually forgot to remove the segue in the storyboard which was directly going from the button to the new view controller. So here is what I did

> 1. Removed the segue which was going directly from the collection view cell button to the next story board
> 2. Created a new segue from the top of the view controller to the next view controller
> 3. Named that segue "showMapSegue"

Build and Run. I got the data successfully in the next view controller. Hope it helps.